# What is the meaning of "equality" in the South African constitution

Tags: constitutional-law, definition, south-africa

In the [South African constitution](https://www.justice.gov.za/legislation/constitution/SAConstitution-web-eng.pdf), the beginning of Chapter 1 reads:

> 1. The Republic of South Africa is one, sovereign, democratic state founded on the following values:
>
>    (a) Human dignity, **the achievement of equality** and the advancement of human rights and freedoms.
>
>    (b) Non-racialism and non-sexism.
>
>    (c) Supremacy of the constitution and the rule of law.
>
>    (d) Universal adult suffrage, a national common
>      voters roll, regular elections and a multi-party system of democratic
>      government, to ensure accountability, responsiveness and openness.

What is the understood meaning of "equality" in the bold phrase? Has this ever been tested in court?